# How to get row count of a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure which accepts a Client number and returns certain data. I have another stored procedure which internally calls the first one and needs to use the Row count from the first stored procedure.
Is there anywhere I can achieve this without using a temporary table (to get the result set) or using an OUT parameter in the first stored procedure.
Thanks.

Comment: See [Erland Sommarskog's](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) article on sharing data between stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already calling your stored procedure from first one, you already have ability to get number of rows returned by using `@@ROWCOUNT` function. Below is example of using `@@RowCount

```
CREATE PROC test1
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.tables
END

CREATE PROC Test2
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    EXEC Test1
    PRINT @@ROWCOUNT
END 

EXEC Test2
```

In my example I just printed that value out, but you can just as simply assign that to a variable in second procedure and use it for something else.